# How do I use Vue.set() properly?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to make an array within my store reactive.

I have currently tried using :key to force update, $forceUpdate() and Vue.set(). I originally was getting and updating the data within the calendar component, but I moved the get data logic to the store in hopes that somehow it would make it reactive. The current attribute shows a red dot on the prescribed v-calendar date. From what I can tell the array is populating with objects with the exact same structure as the single attribute, but it is not reactive.
[image]

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loading: true,
    odata: [],
    attributes: [{
      dates: new Date(),
      dot: 'red',
      customdata: {
        programEventsSystemrecordID: 1234
      }
    }]

  },
  mutations: {
    updateAtts (state) {
      let singleAtt = {}
      let index = 0

      state.odata.forEach((ticket) => {
        Vue.set(singleAtt, 'dot', 'red')
        Vue.set(singleAtt, 'dates', new Date(ticket.ProgramEventsStartdate))
        Vue.set(singleAtt, 'customData', {})

        singleAtt.customData = {
          programEventsSystemrecordID: ticket.ProgramEventsSystemrecordID
        }

        Vue.set(state.attributes, index, singleAtt)

        index++
      })
    },
    updateOdata (state, odata) {
      state.odata = odata
    },
    changeLoadingState (state, loading) {
      state.loading = loading
    }

  },
  actions: {
    loadData ({ commit }) {
      axios.get('https://blackbaud-odata-cal-bizcswpdjy.now.sh')
        .then((response) => {
          commit('updateOdata', response.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .finally(() => {
          console.log(commit('updateAtts'))
          commit('changeLoadingState', false)
        })
    }

  }
})
```

I expect the array that is being populated within vue to update the DOM. There are no error messages.

Comment: Could you make a verifiable fiddle for this? Vuex store should be reactive by default, there is no need to do `Vue.set()` on the states.

Comment: Using Vue.set on an object you just created (so that is not in the state, not reactive) is useless. Just use array.push({my:"obj"}), it works. Currently you set many time same same object to the array.

Comment: @YomS. I will work on a fiddle.

Comment: @Slim when I do `state.odata.forEach((ticket) => {
        state.attributes.push({
          date: new Date(ticket.ProgramEventsStartdate),
          dot: 'red',
          customData: {
            programEventsSystemrecordID: ticket.ProgramEventsSystemrecordID
          }
        })` it still doesn't work

Comment: So there is other problems in code, it's not about state reactivity since state is allways reactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.set is useless in your case. In mostly all cases, it's useless.

It's needed to add new properties in the state that where not initially.

Here, you just have one state property that is build from another.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        loading: true,
        odata: [],
        attributes: [{
            dates: new Date(),
            dot: 'red',
            customdata: {
                programEventsSystemrecordID: 1234
            }
        }]

    },
    mutations: {
        updateAtts (state) {
            state.attributes = state.odata.map(t=>({
                dot: 'red',
                dates: new Date(t.ProgramEventsStartdate),
                customData: {programEventsSystemrecordID: t.ProgramEventsSystemrecordID}
            }))
        },
        updateOdata (state, odata) {
            state.odata = odata
        },
        changeLoadingState (state, loading) {
            state.loading = loading
        }

    },
    actions: {
        loadData ({ commit }) {
            axios.get('https://blackbaud-odata-cal-bizcswpdjy.now.sh')
                .then((response) => {
                    commit('updateOdata', response.data)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    console.log(commit('updateAtts'))
                    commit('changeLoadingState', false)
                })
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: So just to be clear, even though those objects do not actually exist within the array, it should still be reactive? Wondering if I need to use splice somehow? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: No off course, when you create an object in js with {}, it's not reactive. It become reactive as soon as you affect it in an object in the state. Yes with array there is some operations that break reactivity, you have the good link. Never do arr[4] = "thing" or arr.length = 0. Also, never create properties, prepare your state with all properties (even with null). But yes yon can do state.foo = {bar:8} (if you have foo:null initially in your state)

Comment: As @Slim stated above, there were other problems in my code. His answer is helpful in understanding reactivity within Vue.